# Too many parameters in method... (connecting to WebService from WSDL in Delphi XE)

Tags: web-services, delphi, wsdl, delphi-xe

There is an external Web service, respectively, requires the client to him. Based on the WSDL standard for shell Embarcadero RAD Studio XE (Delphi XE) created a unit that usually works well, but in this case there is a caveat - in one of the functions transferred to more than 100 parameters.
When you create an object for calling a web service at runtime get an error "Too many parameters in method 'method name'".
If the number of parameters is reduced to 61, then everything starts to work - calling a web service runs fine and returns a response.
Why is this happening? 
Turned the internet, but the results of zero.

Comment: > 100 method parameters are _so_ too many

Comment: Totally agree with you))) but for me it is an external service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's happening for exactly the reason the error message says. There are too many parameters. The code generator for the SOAP wrapper (in *Rio.pas*) will only allow 252 bytes to be pushed onto the stack to call the wrapped method, which translates to 63 pointer-sized parameters. (Larger parameters may require more bytes, reducing the total number of allowed parameters.)

Comment: Thank you! But why in Builder C++ (RAD Studio XE) there is no this error? (writing now DLL in C++)